# Froala image upload

Tags: image, upload, froala

I'm having trouble configuring image upload in froala

My code is:
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor@latest/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor@latest/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="sample">
<h2>Image upload example.</h2>
<form>
<textarea id="edit" name="content"></textarea>
</form>
</div>


<script>
new FroalaEditor('#edit', {

 imageUploadURL: 'upload_image.php',

  imageUploadParams: {
    id: 'my_editor'
  }
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`
And in upload_image.php:

`

```
 // Allowed extentions.
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");

// Get filename.
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

// Get extension.
$extension = end($temp);

// An image check is being done in the editor but it is best to
// check that again on the server side.
// Do not use $_FILES["file"]["type"] as it can be easily forged.
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

if ((($mime == "image/gif")
|| ($mime == "image/jpeg")
|| ($mime == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($mime == "image/x-png")
|| ($mime == "image/png"))
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
    // Generate new random name.
    $name = sha1(microtime()) . "." . $extension;

    // Save file in the uploads folder.
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], getcwd() . "/uploads/" . $name);

    // Generate response.
    $response = new StdClass;
    $response->link = "/uploads/" . $name;
    echo stripslashes(json_encode($response));
}
```

`

I have a folder at the root of the domain named uploads, with permissions 777, but it still gives me the error "Image cannot be loaded from the passed link".

I've tried changing the code to:
`

```
<script>
(function () {
  const editorInstance = new FroalaEditor('#edit', {
       imageUploadURL: '/UploadFiles',  imageUploadParams: { id: 'my_editor' },
    enter: FroalaEditor.ENTER_P,
    placeholderText: null,
    events: {
      initialized: function () {
        const editor = this
        this.el.closest('form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
          console.log(editor.$oel.val())
          e.preventDefault()
        })
      }
    }
  })
})()  </script>
```

`
It still gives an error, but now a different error "Error during the upload".

I don't understand why in some sites where I look for a solution the imageUploadURL refers to a php script to upload the image and in other sites it refers to a folder on the server.

I've searched in several forums and I can't get this script to work for me, has it happened to anyone else?

I've already tried assigning 777 permissions to the folder, putting a direct or relative path. I put the script in the same folder as the file and I can't upload images.

The best I could do was for the script to put the images in a blob, but then I can't get it to upload to a folder as a jpg file

Answer (score 0):

your 'upload_image.php' file has problem,
replace this one:

```
<?php
 try {
  // File Route.
  $fileRoute = "/uploads/";
  
  $fieldname = "file";
  
  // Get filename.
  $filename = explode(".", $_FILES[$fieldname]["name"]);
  
  // Validate uploaded files.
  // Do not use $_FILES["file"]["type"] as it can be easily forged.
  $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  
  // Get temp file name.
  $tmpName = $_FILES[$fieldname]["tmp_name"];
  
  // Get mime type.
  $mimeType = finfo_file($finfo, $tmpName);
  
  // Get extension. You must include fileinfo PHP extension.
  $extension = end($filename);
  
  // Allowed extensions.
  $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "svg", "blob");
  
  // Allowed mime types.
  $allowedMimeTypes = array("image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg", "image/x-png", "image/png", "image/svg+xml");
  
  // Validate image.
  if (!in_array(strtolower($mimeType), $allowedMimeTypes) || !in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowedExts)) {
  throw new \Exception("File does not meet the validation.");
  }
  
  // Generate new random name.
  $name = sha1(microtime()) . "." . $extension;
  $fullNamePath = dirname(__FILE__) . $fileRoute . $name;

  // Check server protocol and load resources accordingly.
  if (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "off") {
  $protocol = "https://";
  } else {
  $protocol = "http://";
  }
  
  // Save file in the uploads folder.
  move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $fullNamePath);
  
  // Generate response.
  $response = new \StdClass;
  $response->link = $protocol.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).$fileRoute . $name;
  
  // Send response.
  echo stripslashes(json_encode($response));
  
  } catch (Exception $e) {
  // Send error response.
  echo $e->getMessage();
  http_response_code(404);
  }
?>
```

and your first code was true, just replace this and upload your image, your image will save in 'upload' folder.
index.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor@latest/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor@latest/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="sample">
<h2>File upload example.</h2>
<form>
<textarea id="edit" name="content"></textarea>
</form>
</div>

<script>
    
 new FroalaEditor('#edit', {
    
    imageUploadURL: 'upload_image.php',
    
    fileUploadParams: {
    id: 'my_editor'
    }
    })

    var editor = new FroalaEditor('#edit');

editor.opts.events['image.removed'] = function (e, editor, $img) {
  $.ajax({
    // Request method.
    method: 'POST',

    // Request URL.
    url: 'delete_image.php',

    // Request params.
    data: {
      src: $img.attr('src')
    }
  })
  .done (function (data) {
    console.log ('Image was deleted');
  })
  .fail (function (err) {
    console.log ('Image delete problem: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
  })
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```